# partial record not assignable in generic class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

i cannot assign `{b: 1}` to *foo*, but with *bar* and *baz* it works.

In this code i try to exclude all fields of A. The other fields in the inheritance should be allowed

> Type '{ b: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Record<Exclude<keyof T, "a">, unknown>>' ts(2322)

```js
class A {
  a: string
}

class B extends A{
  b: number
}

class C extends B {
  c: string
}

type keyOfModel<T extends B> = keyof Omit<T, keyof A>

const bar: Partial<Record<keyOfModel<B>, unknown>> = {b: 1 }
const baz: Partial<Record<keyOfModel<C>, unknown>> = {b: 1 }

function Test<T extends B>() {
  const foo: Partial<Record<keyOfModel<T>, unknown>> = {b: 1 }
}
```

Typescript 4.5.4